# Converting string input to float64 using ParseFloat in Golang

Tags: go, parsefloat

I've just started learning Go and I'm trying to convert a string from standard input to a float64 so I can perform an arithmetic operation on the input value.

The output returns "0 feet converted to meters gives you 0 meters" regardless of the input value. I can't figure out why the value is zero after invoking ParseFloat on the input.

If someone could please point out to me why this is happening, I would greatly appreciate it.

```
const conversion float64 = 0.3048

func feetToMeters (feet float64) (meters float64) {
  return feet * conversion
}

func main(){
  fmt.Println("\n\nThis program will convert feet to meters for you!\n")

  reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
  fmt.Println("Enter feet value: \n")
  feet, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')

  feetFloat, _ := strconv.ParseFloat(feet, 64)

  meters := feetToMeters(feetFloat)

  fmt.Printf("%v feet converted to meters give you %v meters",feetFloat,meters)
}
```

Comment: `func main(){
  fmt.Println("\n\nThis program will convert feet to meters for you!\n")

  feet := "35"

  feetFloat, _ := strconv.ParseFloat(feet, 64)

  meters := feetToMeters(feetFloat)

  fmt.Printf("%v feet converted to meters give you %v meters",feetFloat,meters)
}` I modified to this and it gives me the right answer. The problem ought to be with the reader. What happens if you `fmt.Println(feet)`?

Comment: Handle the errors returned from reader.ReadString and  strconv.ParseFloat. The errors might provide some insight about the issue.

Comment: Thank you @jonathanGB, I realize now that it was printing a new line character as well.

Comment: @XyMcXface Thank you for the advice. I'll have to learn about handling errors next to avoid further headache!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The problem is that you try to parse `"x.x\n"`, e.g: `1.8\n`. And this returns an error: `strconv.ParseFloat: parsing "1.8\n": invalid syntax`. You can do a `strings.TrimSpace` function or to convert `feet[:len(feet)-1]` to delete `\n` character

With `strings.TrimSpace()` (you need to import `strings` package):

```
feetFloat, _ := strconv.ParseFloat(strings.TrimSpace(feet), 64)
```

Wtih `feet[:len(feet)-1]`:

```
feetFloat, _ := strconv.ParseFloat(feet[:len(feet)-1], 64)
```

Output in both cases:

```
10.8 feet converted to meters give you 3.2918400000000005 meters
```

Comment: Thank you Toni, I didn't even think about the fact that there was a new line character in the string. I appreciate you give me two solutions!

Comment: TrimSpace is a life savior. I thought the ParseFloat will be handling that. :)